# How to log custom status updates using discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I've been working on a blacklisted words option, along with logging when a member of a guild sets a custom status containing a blacklisted word. However, I've run into a problem that I sometimes get the old status same as the new status (only for some guilds tho, others are fine). My code it here:

```
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const newCustomStatus = newPresence.activities[0].state
    const oldCustomStatus = oldPresence.activities[0].state
    console.log('old status: ' + oldCustomStatus)
    console.log('new status: ' + newCustomStatus)
})
```

`oldCustomStatus` is sometimes same as `newCustomStatus` in some guilds, which makes it impossible to log the old status. It only happens in like a half of the guilds the member and bot share.
I thought about making a cache of all statuses on bots start and only toggling the event once, which would allow me to read both the new and old status, since there was always at least one guild with correct info. However, I couldn't then run a per-guild check for blacklisted words, since I don't know a way of reading guild IDs from a user object.

Any way of fixing the broken old and new status? Or a way to get a list of guild IDs the user and bot share?

 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it fires more than once by also logging the guild ID. That seems to solve half of the issue since the next fire takes the new status as both the old and new status. Not sure why it fires more than once tho.
A simple solution for the logger is to use an if statement and compare the new and old statuses, and only log them if they are different:

```
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const newCustomStatus = newPresence.activities[0].state
    const oldCustomStatus = oldPresence.activities[0].state
    if(newCustomStatus != oldCustomStatus) {
        console.log('old status: ' + oldCustomStatus)
        console.log('new status: ' + newCustomStatus)
    }
})
```

Not sure why it fires more than once, this solution is 100% working for me tho.